# how i get id from selected name by combobox?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, combobox

i need to know how i get id of vip from selected name in the combobox 
i make selected value = id 
here my code and how i add to vip money the new money

```
            else
            {
                rs.Item = comboBox1.Text;
                rs.Operation = "ok ";
                rs.Uname = label6.Text;
                rs.Price = textBox2.Text;
                rs.Total_Price = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                rs.Store = textBox3.Text;
                rs.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                vip.money = Convert.ToInt32(vip.money) + ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text));
                rs.Date = DateTime.Now;
                i.Mount = i.Mount - Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                db.Report_Sales.AddObject(rs);
                db.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("ok");
                checkItem();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you try to explain a little bit better, and only post the relevant parts of the code ? It's very hard to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov bro in this add reuslt money to Vip.money but which one will add how i can make specify ID for add buy chosed name in the combo box

Comment: i am so sorry i am new in C# 
    vip.money = Convert.ToInt32(vip.money) + ((Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text));